# Error while linking ThirdControlCamera to gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add some Unity3D assets. I imported the Standard assets from Unity and then I tried to import a character from the Asset store.

I tried to add a third person camera to the character I imported from the asset store. I do the following steps:

1. Drag my new imported character into my scene.
2. Set a 'ThirdPersonController' javascript to it.
3. Add new camera object to the scene.
4. Add a 'ThirdPersonCamera' javascript to it.
5. Set the gameobject camera to the recently created camera.
6. Set the 'Camera transform' for the camera to be the recently imported character.

When I play the game, it says:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the "Skeleton@Skin" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "Skeleton@Skin". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. UnityEngine.Component.get_transform () (at > C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/UnityEngineComponent.cs:20) ThirdPersonController.UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Character Controllers/Sources/Scripts/ThirdPersonController.js:131) ThirdPersonController.Update () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Character Controllers/Sources/Scripts/ThirdPersonController.js:304)

Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is attempting to use a camera component attached the 'Camera transform' variable you assigned in step 6.

I would suggest this variable should be assigned to the camera you added in step 3.